# Import xml data in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, nodes, bulk

I have XML data like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<SettlementFile>
    <Transaction>
        <Identifier>
            <StationID>049215901 </StationID>
            <TransactionTimestamp>2021-04-01T10:39:32</TransactionTimestamp>
        </Identifier>
        <TerminalInfo>
            <TerminalID>21590151</TerminalID>
            <TerminalType>2</TerminalType>
        </TerminalInfo>
        <TransactionInfo>
            <TransactionType>0</TransactionType>
            <TransactionAmount>3.74</TransactionAmount>
            <CurrencyCode>978</CurrencyCode>
            <CustomerInput>
                <Mileage>0</Mileage>
            </CustomerInput>
            <TicketNumber>213510037</TicketNumber>
            <AuthorisationType>1</AuthorisationType>
        </TransactionInfo>
    </Transaction>
</SettlementFile>
```

My SQL Server table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Import_Oase 
(
    StationID            varchar(50) NULL,
    TransactionTimestamp datetime    NULL,
    TicketNumber         int         NULL,
    Mileage              varchar(50) NULL
) ON PRIMARY
```

I'm trying to use this `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT 
    MY_XML.Details.query('StationID')           .value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Details.query('TransactionTimestamp').value('.', 'Datetime'),
    MY_XML.Details.query('TicketNumber')        .value('.', 'Integer'),
    MY_XML.Details.query('Mileage')             .value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')
FROM
    (SELECT
         CAST(MY_XML AS XML)
     FROM
         OPENROWSET(BULK '\\EO-TEST\SQL-Daten\Temp\MY_XML.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)
    ) AS T(MY_XML)
CROSS APPLY 
    MY_XML.nodes('SettlementFile/Transaction/Identifier, SettlementFile/Transaction/TransactionInfo, SettlementFile/Transaction/TransactionInfo/CustomerInput') AS MY_XML (Details);
```

I need to get the result in one line because it is all for 1 transactions. But it is in three different line in SQL.

Comment: Your XML sample is not well-formed. Please edit your question and fix it.

Comment: Also, please provide a DDL for the target table, i.e.  `CREATE TABLE ...`.

Comment: What do you mean by "and I need to get the result in one line because it is all for 1 transactions .but it is in three different line in sql ." - when you say "line" do you mean "row"?

Comment: yes I mean row sorry my english is not good

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

When you are satisfied with the outcome, just uncomment the `INSERT INTO` line.

**SQL**

```
WITH rs (xmlData) AS
(
   SELECT TRY_CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'e:\Temp\ daryosmitan.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)
-- INSERT INTO dbo.Import_Oase (StationID, TransactionTimestamp, TicketNumber, Mileage)
SELECT c.value('(Identifier/StationID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS StationID
    , c.value('(Identifier/TransactionTimestamp/text())[1]', 'DATETIME') AS TransactionTimestamp
    , c.value('(TransactionInfo/TicketNumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS TicketNumber
    , c.value('(TransactionInfo/CustomerInput/Mileage/text())[1]', 'INT') AS Mileage
FROM rs 
   CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('/SettlementFile/Transaction') AS t(c);
```

Comment: thank you so much it is working

Comment: @daryosmitan, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.

Comment: @daryosmitan, You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). 
Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted"

Comment: please how can I choose the xml file with unkonw name : for example :              
       e:\Temp\'unknown_name '.xml

Comment: @daryosmitan, please clarify your question. It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: If I have more than one xml data and I  want all together importing how can I importing together in sql Script . Because this script working for one xml and the name is know but when the xml name in unknown and more than one data xml for example 3 data xml with different name hwo can Iimporting.

Comment: Unfortunately, the file name should be a literal string. It is not a parameter that could be passed via variable. so you need to create a dynamic SQL string. 